# given min="1935" max="2022" step="1" how to change default from min to max

Tags: html, forms, input, max, default

I have a form that asks for alumni names and graduation years (1 of each field per alumni).
The graduation year field has a scroll bar to choose a year from min="1938" to max="2022".
I would like to leave the graduation year field blank using value="".
The problem I run into is that the min value is the first option provided by the scroll bar if no value is provided in the code.
I would like it to provide the 2022 option and scroll down from that as need be, rather than allow it to provide 1938 and scroll up from that - I figure the most likely graduation years will be closer to the max value.
How can I set the scroll bar to provide the max value without specifying it as a value?
Placing the max value before the min value doesn't work even with the step as -1.
The code looks like this:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Class of"/>
  <input type="number" name="os2" maxlength="4" min="1935" max="2022" step="1" value="" style="width:50px"required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Provide Graduation Year')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the effect you asked for by changing this line to:

```html
<input type="number" name="os2" maxlength="4" min="1935" max="2022" step="-1" value="2022" style="width:50px"required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please Provide Graduation Year')"<br><br>
```

I only changed the "value" attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, setting a value works, but also shows. I was really hoping to override the default selection (which is always to use whatever the min value is when no value is set) since setting a value shows in the box pre-selection; which I was hoping to avoid for a cleaner "look" to the form. Since there was a possibility that only one or two names would be filled in on the form, I didn't want a page with empty alumni name fields showing dates for the graduation year already filled in. I tried using `&nbsp;` (e.g. `value="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2022"` but still get 1938 as start #.